# How to select rows based on a list of values

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table with +250K rows.

I need to get only the rows that match any string in a list of string values (this can be anywhere from a few to +100 values).

I have tried this approach:
[SQL Select where values in List<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602544/sql-select-where-values-in-liststring)

But sometimes this fails because my query gets too long.

At the moment I am fetching the entire table and then processing it in LINQ.

But this doesn't feel right...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Match all strings or any of them ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Any of them, will update question accordingly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But sometimes this fails because my query gets too long.

It appears that you have picked the accepted answer to the question that you have linked, namely, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/602555/335858):

```
String query = "select * from table where RecordId in ({0});";
String formatted = String.Format(query, String.Join(",", list.ToArray()));
```

One drawback to this approach is that the query grows proportionally to the total length of all strings in your list, so if your list has many strings that are very long, you are running the chance of exceeding the allowable length of the query.

Fortunately, there is another answer to that question that is free of this problem - namely, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/602621/335858):

```
IEnumerable<TableRow> query =
  from t in db.Table
  where RecordList.Any(r => t.RecordId == r)
  select t;
```

Rather than inserting string values directly into the query string, it uses an approach that leads to generating a parameterized query. Now the length depends only on the number of items in your list, but not on their length. So if this query works for a list of max length of 100 items or so, it would continue working regardless of the total string length in your list.

This approach does have a limit - depending on the RDBMS, the total number of items in the `IN` list could be capped. However, the default caps are pretty high - around 1000 for Oracle, or 2000 for MS SQL Server, so your queries with 100 items or so should be well under this limit.

Comment: Exactly, I have tried the string concatenation solution. I will give your solution a try, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could add your 100+ values to a temp table and then query `SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE YourValue IN (SELECT YourValue FROM #TempValues)`.

Comment: Nice suggestion, but unfortunately I can't add/edit tables in the DB.